# Start sprint date and end sprint date in Agile for TFS2010

Tags: tfs, agile, sprint

I'm trying Agile with Team Foundation Server 2010 for the fist time.

I'd like input for each sprint a start date and an end date but I think that is not possible actually.

Do you have some hints how extend it for this data?

Answer (score 0):

Enri, each sprint will have an excel workbook associated to it. Within that, in the settings worksheet, you should be able to specify the start and end dates.